# If four variables are equal

Tags: vba, excel

I want to check if four different variables are equal to each other. I've got the following statement:

```
If a = b = c = d then
```

All of the variables contain "06-12-2014", unfortunately excel doesn't enter the 'if'-statement.
Now I found out this may be a way of writint the if statement that isn't correct. I can of course make something like the following, but I feel like there must be another way, is there?

```
If a=b and b=c and c=d then
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try inserting all variable to compare into an array and then use a function.
Here an example:

```
Sub MyTest()
Dim TestArr() As Variant

a = "06-12-2014"
b = "06-12-2014"
c = "06-12-2014"
d = "06-12-2014"
TestArr = Array(a, b, c, d)
If Equal_In_Array(TestArr) Then
    MsgBox ("All are Equal")
Else
    MsgBox ("Something isn't Equal")
End If
End Sub

Public Function Equal_In_Array(mArr() As Variant) As Boolean
Equal_In_Array = True
For x = LBound(mArr) To UBound(mArr)
    If mArr(x) <> mArr(LBound(mArr)) Then
        Equal_In_Array = False
        Exit For
    End If
Next x
End Function
```

**EDIT**: 
You can also use `ParamArray` to pass directly the values and to avoid declaring a new array:

```
Sub MyTest()
a = "06-12-2014"
b = "06-12-2014"
c = "06-12-2014"
d = "06-12-2014"
If Are_Equal(a, b, c, d) Then
    MsgBox ("All are Equal")
Else
    MsgBox ("Something isn't Equal")
End If
End Sub

Public Function Are_Equal(ParamArray mArr() As Variant) As Boolean
Equal_In_Array = True
For x = LBound(mArr) To UBound(mArr)
    If mArr(x) <> mArr(LBound(mArr)) Then
        Equal_In_Array = False
        Exit For
    End If
Next x
End Function
```

Comment: @Grafit Iadded an improved solution

Answer (score 9):

You can create a flexible function with variable number of parameters in this way:

```
Function AllSame(ParamArray ar()) As Boolean
    AllSame = True : If UBound(ar) < 1 Then Exit Function
    For Each p In ar
        If p <> ar(0) Then
            AllSame = False : Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

You can use it with any number of variables

```
If AllSame(a, b, c, d, e, f) Then ....
```

Comment: I improved my answer with a your idea: +1 ;)

Answer (score 1):

Compare everything to `a`?

```
equal = areSame(a, b, c, d)

Function areSame(match As String, ParamArray rest()) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To UBound(rest)
        If (match <> rest(i)) Then Exit Function
    Next
    areSame = True
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been answered, but I wanted to provide a different solution which doesn't require a loop.

```
a = "06-12-2014"
b = "06-12-2014"
c = "06-12-2014"
d = "06-12-2014"
TestArr = Array(a, b, c, d)
If UBound(Filter(TestArr, a)) = 3 Then
    MsgBox "All match"
Else
    MsgBox "Doesnt match"
End If
```